# Woocommerce StoreFront Showing Incorrect Subtotal in Customer Total

Tags: themes

I am using StoreFront with Woocommerce, very basic as I only have one product with variations. The product is 'CESAA Membership' and I have 6 variations...the issue I am facing can be explained with just these two variations:

- [Students/retired/unwaged][1 year]
- [Students/retired/unwaged][2 years]

The first one is $25, the second one is $35.

I just had a new order come in and it shows the following:

[image: Item added twice]

As you can see, the item was added twice but it is essentially the same item. The subtotal shows as $50 (from 2 * $25) but the total shows only $25, which is correct.

The variations depend on two attributes I have defined: Membership Type and Membership Duration:

[image: Product Attributes]

Why on Earth is it adding that extra product? This will really confuse customers as they will think their card was charged with twice the amount.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.